# complexity of building heap: why can one substitute a bounded infinite series into a bounded sum?

Tags: power-series, computational-complexity

Partially into the derivation, the author substitutes the result of this infinite series,

$$ \sum_{h=0}^\infty hx^h = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} $$

into the bounded sum,

$$\sum_{j=0}^h j\left(\frac{1}2\right)^j.$$

The author says "since the infinite series is bounded, we can use it instead as an easy approximation." I don't understand why. Can I generally do this?

Comment: Good catch on the bounded sum. As for the result, just take the geometric series, find the derivative and multiply both sides by x and you'll reach this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the terms in the series are nonnegative and the partial sums are bounded above, we can conclude that each partial sum is bounded above in particular by the least upper bound - the limit of the partial sums, which is simply the infinite series.

More precisely, I am referring to the following theorem:

> If $a_n$ is a monotonically increasing sequence of real numbers, i.e. $a_n\leqslant a_{n+1}$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists if and only if $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence, that is, there exists $M$ such that $a_n\leqslant M$ for all $n$.

For if the set $\{a_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ is bounded above, it has a least upper bound $a$, and given $\varepsilon>0$ we may choose $N$ so that $n\geqslant N$ implies $a-\varepsilon<a_n<a$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$. Conversely, if $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded, then for any $a\in\mathbb R$, there exists $n$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $a_n-a >1$, so $a_n$ does not converge to $a$.

Now, given a sequence $\{a_n\}$, there is the corresponding sequence of partial sums $\{S_n\}$ where $$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k. $$ If $a_k\geqslant 0$ for all $k$, then $S_1=a_1$ and for each $n\geqslant0$, $$S_{n+1}=S_n + a_{n+1}\geqslant S_n, $$ so $\{S_n\}$ is a monotonically increasing sequence. It follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ exists if and only if $\{S_n\}$ is bounded.

Comment: What do you mean by "the partial sums are bounded" and "each partial sum is bounded by the least upper bound"? Sorry, I'm not very familiar with this.